# If i do print_r in PHP, it prints the array in junk

Tags: php

How can I print the array in a Tree-like format--making it easier to read?

Comment: Note that `print_r` prints in plain text and not HTML. So you need to look at the source code to see the original output.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
<pre><?php print_r($var); ?></pre>
```

It will give the proper tree structure that HTML's whitespace policy trims out.

Comment: As an addenda, I'll point out that I find that `<pre><?php print_r($var,true); ?></pre>` gives more consistent (tree-like) results (though I haven't researched *why* that is)

Answer (score 12):

Are you wrapping the output in `<pre>` tags? That should get you pretty decent output, because it will show the spaces. Another option would be to install the [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) extension, which then can [replace `var_dump`](http://xdebug.org/docs/display) so that it generates more-readable HTML output.

Comment: +1 for xdebug. The replacement `var_dump` it provides supports arrays very nicely, almost eliminating the need for `print_r` entirely.

Answer (score 4):

```
function pr($var)
{
    print '<pre>';
    print_r(htmlspecialchars($var));
    print '</pre>';
}

pr($myArray);
```

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` please. OK, so security isn't a concern for debugging code (though escaping certainly a habit you should always have), but any ‘<’ characters in your variables will mess up the output.

Comment: `function pr($var) { print '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars(print_r($var, true)) . '</pre>'; }`

Answer (score 2):

I found it's a good idea to print_r as follows

```
printf("<pre>%s</pre>", print_r($array, true));
```

It may not be ideal, but it's easier to read.

Comment: You need the second argument to print_r to be boolean true for it to return the value and not just print it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at [Zend_Debug](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.debug.html), a relatively plug-and-play module from the Zend Framework which does an excellent job at effectively dumping complex variables.

Usage:

```
$my_var = new StdObject(); // or whatever
Zend_Debug::dump($my_var); 
die; // optional, prevents routing, forwarding away, etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could print it into the error log:

```
error_log(print_r($myarray,1));
```

Note that you will see \n instead of carriage returns because it has to be collapsed in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Mabe the output looks like junk in the webpage. Try looking at the source of the page and it will be in tree-like format I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using `var_export($array)`?

It formats values with **parsable php syntax**

And even when you forget to output `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags,
while not very easy on the eye,
its output still makes more sense then `print_r` informal bunch of data.

Answer (score 0):

As many people previously mention, make sure to wrap it around a `<pre>` tag.

I would take an extra precautions to make sure nothing is wrapping that `<pre>` as well, such as `<p>` or `<div>` with a CSS class that can override the Pre's Style